# get internal links from Introduction in article

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-api

For a given article on Wikipedia, I would like to use the Mediawiki API to extract the internal links from the introduction section of an article.

Eximilar to the `prop=extracts&exintro=` setting but with the contents of the links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the lead wikitext with either `extracts` or [`revisions`](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query%2Brevisions) for section 0 (the first has sanity checks against a very long intro / an article with no section headings at all, but might be cut off at an awkward position), pass it to [`parse`](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=parse) and set `prop=links`.

Comment: Can you give an example of this? I am fairly new to the Mediawiki API. Thanks!

Comment: For example, I am trying:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Albert%20Einstein&prop=links|extracts&exintro=

However, that seems to be doing two things simultaneously. I would like to get only the interwiki links which are in the introduction to Albert Einstein.

Comment: You can't do that in a single API request. You need to get the wikitext for the slice of the article you are interested in, then parse it.

Comment: Thanks @Tgr. I will give that a try. Please let me know if you come across any examples.